# [PHP]Download Code using header() not working

Tags: php, download

I'm developing file sharing service and I tried to make download codes, But only a white page displays!

Here is the code of `down.php`

```
<?php
$var = $_GET["fid"];

        $fr = 'realname.txt'; //fake file name.
$filepath = '/home/user32222/public_html/parafile/'.$var.'/filestorage/downloadthisfile.txt' //In this case,  file extension is txt but I want to download file with any extension even file extension is nothing
//I tried these codes but it not worked!!
                    /*header('Pragma: public');     // required 
                    header('Expires: 0');       
                    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fr\"");
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
                    readfile($filepath);*/


                    $size   = filesize($filepath);
                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fr); //Download Client Program think file's name is realname.txt ($fr)

                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);


?>
```

Comment: You forgot a quote after `$fr = 'realname.txt`. Missing semicolon after `'/home/user32222/public_html/parafile/'.$var.'/filestorage/downloadthisfile.txt'`, as welll

Comment: @PHPglue Oh I missed the ' and ;. But it doesn't work now...

Comment: what about turning on error reporting to see what kind of error PHP is throwing? It will be a lot easier to solve then!!!

Answer (score 0):

the response is being returned empty because you did not read the file you want to download.this can be done using the `readfile()` function

try this code:

```
<?php
     $var = $_GET["fid"];
     $fr = 'realname.txt'; //fake file name.
     $filepath =  '/home/user32222/public_html/parafile/'.$var.'/filestorage/downloadthisfile.txt';
     $size   = filesize($filepath);
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fr); 
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
     readfile($filepath);
?>
```